# Getting Error /usr/bin/env: node : Permission Denied

Tags: python, linux, node.js, centos, odoo

I have done my ODOO v9 installation on my server(Centos). Everything has been installed successfully . Login page is also working but after login I am getting a page with following error

```
/usr/bin/env : node : Permission Denied
```

I tried to change the permission but my issue is not solved. Is anyone know what is this error?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: have you tried by root access?

Comment: Yes I tried using root access . but it is showing  /usr/bin/env : node :  no such file or directory

Comment: I have  reinstalled  nodejs. Then I tried to run the application I got another error   QWebException: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 208946: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Oh! I'm also trying to setup Odoo 9 at my Mac. Same Error! But mine is **env: node: Permission denied**. The latter is same. :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- When This Type is Problem Occurred Then Following Command in your Terminal
- Most simple way is to install `nodeJs` with its package manager `npm`. `Nodejs` is in the repositories, but that one is a bit outdated, instead you could use this `ppa`:

  ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
  ```

( https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager ) Especially if you're doing JavaScript/Web development nodejs is pretty important today.

- At this point it's simply (as stated on http://lesscss.org)

  ```
   sudo npm install -g less
  ```
- if you already installed lessc then above command run Two Times..

  ```
  sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
  ```

Comment: So, whenever this happens, then we have to install nodejs again?

Comment: No if nodejs install one time and this error is solved

Comment: This is not working for an Ubuntu box. Sorry! The repo isn't showing as compatible. I'm getting this error: `The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason you'd get the error you describe is that your distro package maintainers have reserved the name 'node' for something besides nodejs.  If this is the case, the binary you want to use (npm will want to use) will be called 'nodejs'.  To check this, run:

`which node`

If you don't get a path to a node binary back, it may be your problem is what I described above, then try:

`which nodejs`

If you get back a binary path, then you can then take the output, eg: `/usr/bin/nodejs` and run:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

And you'll have a functioning nodejs installation.

Don't ask me why the maintainers of npm on these platforms aren't calling to nodejs.  And don't ask me why a package installed by less than a tenth of a percent of linux users gets to own the name 'node' over 'nodejs' which a very large fraction - I suspect a double digit percentage - of linux users install.  Some things just can't be explained.