# /usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux

As the title suggests I am receiving the error

```
/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied
```

when trying to run

```
npm run build
```

for my react app. The following link is the leadup to this point with all that I've done and tried, not to be included here for the sake of not duplicating questions [Error with react-scripts in npm run build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928661/error-with-react-scripts-in-npm-run-build/70928883#70928883).

Additionally, I have viewed this posting, [Getting Error /usr/bin/env: node : Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645747/getting-error-usr-bin-env-node-permission-denied), and it was unhelpful to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is shown if you run `ls -l "$(which node)"` ?

Comment: This sounds like your `node` executable isn't, well, executable. Try `which node` to see which `node` your computer is trying to run; chances are it's not something in e.g. `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` if this is the symptom.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 mod mod 81232432 Jan 18 13:48 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node
@md2perpe

Comment: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node is what pops up. Should I look up how to make it a an executable file then? @AKX

Comment: The rights `-rwxr-xr-x` tell us that `node` is executable. What happens if you run `node` or `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node` (try both)?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb but what do you mean by run node? @md2perpe

Comment: Type those as commands in the console, just as you did with `ls -l "$(which node)"`.

Comment: @md2perpe I had no idea node had its own prompt window, learn something new every day. This is what pops up for just node, same for folder

Welcome to Node.js v17.4.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>

Comment: Thus node is runnable so that is not the problem.

Comment: @md2perpe so if thats the case what could be the other possibilities for the problem?

Comment: I have no idea right now.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the effort, I'll give it a day or 2 to see if anyone else chimes in @md2perpe

Comment: What happens if you run `/usr/bin/env node`?

Comment: @md2perpe It does the same thing as just executing node normally

Comment: Run `hash -r` (assuming you're using bash as shell) and see if `/usr/bin/env node` still works after that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue ended up being a matter of file ownership. Root was the owner of many things for the project rather than my profile. Simply changed the ownership from root to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied

Answer (score 15):

I was working in a dockerized node environment and noticed that the mounted source code directory had different ownership (running the container as root) from host environment. Changing the ownership using:

`chown -R root:root .`

made the error go away for me!

Comment: solved it for me

Comment: How do  make this permanent? it seems i have to run that every time i ssh into the server. I am not even working a dockerized environment.

Comment: Once you run the command, it should be permanent. Unless, some other process is changing the permissions again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811564/sh-1-node-permission-denied

Comment: After the chown, I needed to add `--unsafe-perm` to my npm command to make it work eg `npm run prod --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 2):

For me, re-installing node with NVM solved the issue:

- [Install nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)
- `nvm install 14`
- `nvm use 14`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else hitting this, there is another avenue of investigation. There might be another factor affecting execute permissions. There's an `exec` flag on drive mounts to enable script execution (neat safety feature for automounted usb sticks!). So if your code is on a drive that you've mounted, you need that option set to run scripts on it. Tell-tale signs are the permissions on the script being correct (appropriate user, group and execute bits set), but it still complaining about the shebang line (1st line) being the permission denied. Also, if you type `mount`, you might see `noexec` set on the mount point where your source code is (it may not show here if exec is set). How your mount is set up varies greatly, but a place to start is your `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score -2):

you should running command as super user `sudo npm run build`